# How to read a columns from text file and store it in array? Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, split

In text file every line include some number of words. It looks like

```
split time not big
every cash flu green big
numer note word
swing crash car out fly sweet
```

How to split those lines and store it in array? I need to do with array something like this

```
for i in $file

do
echo "$array[0]"
echo "$array[2]"
done
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want to store the lines of a file in an array? Or do you have a single line that you want to split into words? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to split words to array from every line. Need something like this
`for every_line_in File ; do
item1=$array_form_line_0[0]
item2=$array_form_line_0[3]

done`

Comment: Do you want the line in an array, or just in `item1` and `item2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the file line by line with `read` and assign the line to an array. It's rather fragile and might break depending on the file content.

```
while read line; do 
   array=( $line )
   echo "${array[0]}"
   echo "${array[2]}"
done < file
```

A better way to parse text file is to use `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1; print $3}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need an array, then. You could just do this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    read -r item1 item2 item3 <<< "$line"
    printf '%s\n%s\n' "$item1" "$item3"
done < "$file"
```

But if you want to, you can make `read` give you an array, too:

```
    read -ra array <<< "$line"
    printf '%s\n%s\n' "${array[0]}" "${array[2]}"
```